# AVAssetExportSession no audio (iPhone), works on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, avfoundation

We're trying to take an existing video with audio (.mov) and make a more email friendly version. Seems pretty straightforward and the code below does just what we need ... almost.

On an iPad2 (4.3.3) it works in debug & release builds all of the time. On the iPhone 4 (4.3.3) or 4th gen iPod Touch there's no audio. From time to time, no obvious correlation as to what triggers it, it will start working on the iPhone. Delete the app, rebuild/install, and it no longer works.

```
AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:sourcePath] options:nil];
session = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset
                                       presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];
session.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destPath];
session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
[session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(conversionFinished)
                           withObject:nil
                        waitUntilDone:NO]; }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you playing the movie too, for example in an MPMoviePlayer?  I have had some occasional export quirks while playing or using other initialized assets with the same URLs.

Comment: I've tested it both ways, no difference. We create the movie using AVAssetWriter and are calling [assetWriterInput markAsFinished] and [assetWriter finishWriting] on it. It plays on the device just fine (or on desktop after xfer).

Comment: Actually that's a GREAT clue! If I force-quit the app after making the recording and then go in to create the smaller video it works. So now to find out why.

Comment: Another thought is memory.  Getting any memory warnings?  One time I was getting memory warnings and lost some of my tracks.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Peter. I went through the code to ensure that all other assets are released/finished and now it seems to have stabilized. Still need to put in a memory warning generator to see if that drives the problem.

Comment: I have a similar issue, a bit like the one in this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911194). The trouble seem to come from playing the related assets in an `AVPlayer`, but I could not figure out the precise circumstances.